# How online compilers take care of fork bomb

Tags: algorithm, fork, system-calls

One can carry out a denial of service attack using fork bomb ( infinite fork ). The process table would soon be full and the system will crash.

How does online compilers ( like in programing contests ) take care of such code. Do they have time constraint. If some program has time limit of few seconds, they process table will be filled by than and the system crashes.

I am interested to know how they implement the safety measures.

I am not sure if the question is appropriate here. If not, point me in right direction.

Comment: How is the question scope broad? Can i make it any simpler. I want the way fork bomb is prevented

Comment: man setrlimit, look for setrlimit(RLIMIT_NPROC).

Comment: Online judges typically just don't let you spawn new processes or threads at all. I'm surprised HackerRank lets you do that, since it give you an unfair advantage to be able to use more than one CPU core.

Comment: @NiklasB. Might be a bug in their system

Answer (score 3):

Generally, such programs are run in a constrained environment (aka a "jail") in which they have limited access to system calls.  For example, they may not call 'fork', or they are given a version of 'fork' which always fails or aborts the process.

Comment: Not true. I tried fork 2 times in one environment and it executed correctly and outputed id 8 times. So I don't think limited access is true or it always fails. I tried hackerrank

Comment: Are you able to bring the site down with a fork bomb?  If not, then your program is running in a constrained environment.  The two simple examples I gave are not exhaustive.

Comment: Nope can't bring the site down. I got answer from from above comment. We can limit process in linux.